# Run Dispel (1999) on Windows 8.1

Tags: backwards-compatibility, windows-8, dispel

I want to play Dispel on rather modern PC: Windows 8.1 (x64), Intel i5-3570k, Radeon r9 380.

This is an old game (1999) and unpopular, so it was never remastered or even patched for systems, that are newer then XP. It's really buggy also, so it may have hardware problems because of using dirty hacks instead of normal video driver API. Nevertheless, it requires DirectX 7.

If I try to run the game as administrator (otherwise it won't work), I get "Cannot install driver" message. The same problem in every compatibility mode.

If I try to launch Dispel under Windows XP in Oracle VM Virtualbox, I get another error: "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000005)." This happens regardless on 2D/3D acceleration enabled.

What other tricks can I try (excluding installing XP in dualboot)? Can I get some information about the error with any kind of debugger (for example, which particular library initialization failed)?

Comment: I'd say that due to the fact that it's unpopular there's probably no way to play Dsipel on Windows 8.1. Of course I'm no technical whiz so I wouldn't advise taking my word for it..

Comment: Did you install direct x7? I'm thinking your card itself has something to do with this.

Comment: As it's from 1999, you may want to try a Win98 VM,  that's at least the OS this game was designed for.

Comment: @Thecheater887 Yes, I've installed it on main OS. But I didn't in virtual one, because I get get an error when running DirectX setup.

Comment: @Dulkan No effect, still getting this error. I think, the problem is, I'm not using Intel graphics.

Comment: Intel graphics? In 1999? Intel didn't do any graphics whatsoever till 2008. You'd certainly need to install DirectX on the VM. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Dulkan I mean Intel videocard, not Intel Graphics technology.

Comment: @JustLogin Wow, didn't even know Intel made video cards back then. But still, your assumption has to be nonsense. If the game required an Intel video card, nobody would have been to play it, because on one used those and according to wikipedia their performance was terrible.

Comment: @Dulkan thanks for explanation. So, I'll check what's the problem with DirectX in virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a good repack from Nelex, which runs under new systems. I has videos cut, but at least it works.